# Client is Offline error while using firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a small database system for my client that will capture his website's registered users name and there spent amount. Based on there spent amount he will get some gifts.
Using firebase realtime database i am able to store user spent amount but when i try to get data from database. I am getting the following Error from the line:
`get(child(userDbRef, "User-ID-"+userID))`:

`"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Client is offline."`

`initailData();` will work if user does not have data stored already and if the data has been stored once then `runInitialFunction();` will work and get/retrieve data from database.

Here is my code

```js
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAfA1HIkamXEFtDidPkpxaltDVsWpFWepE",
    authDomain: "thundersmmpanel-77fb2.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://thundersmmpanel-77fb2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "thundersmmpanel-77fb2",
    storageBucket: "thundersmmpanel-77fb2.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "867306490186",
    appId: "1:867306490186:web:93407cb6d8b0e9abe9d9b3"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  
  //<!--my code-->
  import {getDatabase, ref, set, get, child, update}
  from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-database.js";
  
  const userID = {{user['id']}};
  const userName = "{{user['username']}}";
  const pointsDb = getDatabase();
  
  //<!-- initial data -->
  function initailData() {
    set(ref(pointsDb, "User-ID-"+userID),{
        UserName: userName,
        InitialSpent: {{user['spent']}},
        ThisRun: 1
    })
    .then(function(){
        alert("Done");
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        alert("Error "+error);
    });
    console.log("initailData");
  }
  
  
  function runInitialFunction() {
    const userDbRef = ref(pointsDb)
    get(child(userDbRef, "User-ID-"+userID)).then((snapshot)=>{
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            
        }else{
            initailData();
        }
    });
    console.log("runInitialFunction");
  }
  runInitialFunction();
```

Comment: Which specific line in the code you shared is giving that error?

Comment: This one `get(child(userDbRef, "User-ID-"+userID)).then((snapshot)=>{`
and i am sure the get function is not working.

Comment: Getting the data from the server requires that there is a connection to that server; it can't be done while the client is offline.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. but i am actually not getting what server you are talking about my website server, firebase database server or something else? please make it lil clear.